# VBA Macro Help - Clear Table and Cell Formatting from Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear all Table Formatting and Cell Formatting from entire workbooks.  This code gets me most of the way there, but I do not want to clear cell contents.

I have tried modifying this behavior by removing the Selection.ClearContents string.  This makes the code nonfunctional, however.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Sub ClearAll()

    Set wbook = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each sht In wbook.Worksheets
       sht.Activate
       sht.Cells.Select
       Selection.ClearContents
       Selection.ClearFormats ' edit: clear formats too
       sht.Cells(1, 1).Select ' edit: select the first cell to cancel selection of the whole sheet
    Next sht


End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "clear table formatting" do you mean that you want any tables converted back to ranges?

Comment: Correct. All the tables need to be converted to ranges. Then all cell formatting needs to be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by non-functional. Anyway you don't need to select or activate anything.

```
Sub ClearAll()

Dim sht As Worksheet, wbook As Workbook, t As ListObject

Set wbook = ActiveWorkbook

For Each sht In wbook.Worksheets
    For Each t In sht.ListObjects
        t.Unlist
    Next t
    sht.Cells.ClearFormats
Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Regarding "Non-Functional", if I remove the "Selection.ClearContents" line from the macro, it doesn't complete any actions when I run it in Excel.  The above code doesn't seem to perform any actions on these spreadsheets.

Comment: Colour a cell yellow, run the code and let me know what happens.

Comment: It got rid of the yellow.  All the table formatting is still there.  Maybe we need a clear table?

Comment: Can you try amended code above? Hadn't realised that formats does not affect tables.

Comment: That just freezes excel up.  Is there a way just to clear character formatting?

Comment: Try it on a small workbook. Don't really see why that should be a problem though. Did it actually crash or just take a long time to finish?